# React Native Expo In App Purchase setPurchaseListener position

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, expo

I am implementing In App Purchase function in Expo bare workflow using Expo-In-App-Purchase library.
In their [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/#inapppurchasessetpurchaselistenercallback-result-iapqueryresponse--void) we need to implement `setPurchaseListener` on a global scope.

My question would be, anyone know where does global scope means?

Answer (score 1):

Globally typically means in App.js.  Using the template from [Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/#inapppurchasessetpurchaselistenercallback-result-iapqueryresponse--void), it should look like something below in your App.js file (I am using class components).

```
setUpIAP = async() => {
    // Set purchase listener
    await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
    await InAppPurchases.setPurchaseListener(({ responseCode, results, errorCode }) => {
      // Purchase was successful
      if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.OK) {
        results.forEach(purchase => {
          if (!purchase.acknowledged) {
            console.log(`Successfully purchased ${purchase.productId}`);
            // Process transaction here and unlock content...

            // Then when you're done
            InAppPurchases.finishTransactionAsync(purchase, true);
          }
        });
      }

      // Else find out what went wrong
      if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        console.log('User canceled the transaction');
      } else if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.DEFERRED) {
        console.log('User does not have permissions to buy but requested parental approval (iOS only)');
      } else {
        console.warn(`Something went wrong with the purchase. Received errorCode ${errorCode}`);
      }
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setUpIAP();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to handle if you have to send a custom variable to setPurchaseListener? Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575670/react-native-expo-in-app-purchase-send-custom-variable-to-setpurchaselistener)?